# Is there a way to avoid changeset commit on RTC?

Tags: commit, rtc, changeset

Many developpers in my team have changeset named "NO COMMIT", because they did some modifications just used for local purpose.

Is there a way in RTC to disable the ability to commit this kind of changeset ?

Somethings like "protect changeset" or "lock changeset".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of committing, you can create an [RTC patch](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_scm_patch.html&scope=null)

> right-click the change set or Unresolved folder that contains the files that you want to include in the patch and click `New > Patch`.

That way, you can quickly:

- isolate a changeset as a patch
- discard it from the local workspace
- commit and deliver the rest
- then  re-apply the patch.